# Specifying path in init script of Atom

Tags: java, path, coffeescript, julia, atom-editor

I am trying to specify the following path in inti.coffee for atom to load

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/home/username/julia-1.6.1/lib/julia/libstdc++.so.6
```

This returns

Failed to load `/home/username/.atom/init.coffee`

`Javascript error: Invalid regular expression flags username`

So I tried,

```
 export LD_PRELOAD="/home/username/julia-1.6.1/lib/julia/libstdc++.so.6"
```

And this returns,

Failed to load `/home/username/.atom/init.coffee`

`Javascript error: Unexpected token export`

Could someone suggest what's the right way to specify the path for LD_PRELOAD?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what your end result is here? It is not clear what `inti.coffee` is